# How to handle Back Press on View Pager inside Fragment in Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

Hello guys i'm facing some problem

so i have an Activity which contain 3 fragments, which can change fragment everytime user pressed button

FragmentA -> FragmentB -> FragmentC

but there is ViewPager2 in FragmentB which has 3 fragments, so it could be like this

Fragment A -> FragmentB 1st Page -> FragmentB 2nd Page -> FragmentB 3rd Page -> Fragment C

the problem is when i do a backpressed in FragmentC is not back to FragmentB with 3rd page immediately, instead i should do a backpressed 3 times and it goes straight to Fragment A not Fragment B

Fragment C -> (backpressed 3 times) -> Fragment A

how could this happened ? is it posible to achieve something like this with ViewPager in the fragment ? this is what i want to achieved

Fragment C -> (backpressed) -> FragmentB 3rd Page -> (backpressed) -> FragmentB 2nd Page -> (backpressed) -> FragmentB 1st Page -> (backpressed) -> Fragment A

This is the code i used to switch Fragment in Activity

```
private val fragmentA by lazy { FragmentA.newInstance() }
private val fragmentBWithViewPager by lazy { FragmentB.newInstance() }
private val fragmentC by lazy { FragmentC.newInstance() }

private fun switchFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
    val trasaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    trasaction.replace(viewBinding.layoutFragment.id, fragment)
    trasaction.addToBackStack(null)
    trasaction.commit()
}

fun onNextPressed(fragment: Fragment) {
    when (fragment) {
            fragmentA -> switchFragment(fragmentBWithViewPager)
            fragmentBWithViewPager -> switchFragment(fragmentC)
            fragmentC -> toast("Last Fragment")
    }
}
```

Any suggestion ? anything would be helpful, thanks in advance

Comment: Because all the fragments are added to the backstack. Try to override the `onBackPressed` and do what you wants.

Comment: Can you provide a github sample on this so that we can test with it

Comment: @G
@Zain i can't provide it at this moment

Comment: @GuanHongHuang should i override it in activity ?, so should i check if the fragment contains the view pager or not ?